# PHP image extension

Tags: php, image, extension-methods

I have successfully created an upload image form that will allow the user to upload their images and store them in a certain folder. But the problem is that I don't know how to use those images with different extensions? Because some of them are PNG, some are JPG, and some are GIF.

How can I loop through them all?

Comment: Please post your PHP code, otherwise how are we supposed to help?

Comment: I do not have a code. My only code is related on uploading the file which I do not have a problem with. My problem is I do not know how to  loop and display those images with different extention

Comment: Try `foreach (glob('/path/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $file) { ... }`

Comment: To learn about this stuff the manual is the best place to start. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php. Then try coming up with your own solution. If it doesn't work, come back with code, that's how SO usually works...

Answer (score 0):

On upload you should convert images to JPG or another extension so they are all the same using GD from PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

Other than that you can get the extension of the image by using exif_imagetype().

-- Since Your Updated Question

You can use glob() in PHP to loop through all files in a folder.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

To correctly fix this issue you should save all file names to a database so you don't have to guess the file names. Also use GD tools to make all images the same type to further make getting images easier and you can change quality and compression to save on space.

Answer (score 0):

getimagesize() will return an associative array where one key is 'mime'. That would let you determine file type.